# Catch tap event on TextFormField

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I am trying to catch the tap event on TextFormField into a flutter Form.

I use a GestureDetector to do that with the TextFormField as child but nothing is firing when a click on it :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Recherche de sorties')),
      body: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidate: _autovalidate,
          child: new ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                new DatePicker(
                  labelText: 'Date',
                  selectedDate: widget.request.dateDebut,
                  initialDate: widget.request.dateDebut,
                  firstDate: new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: -1)),
                  lastDate: new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 365 * 4)),
                  selectDate: (DateTime value) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.request.dateDebut = value;
                    });
                  },
                  datePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.date_range),
                ),
                new InputDecorator(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Rayon',
                    hintText: '-- Choisissez un rayon --',
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.settings_backup_restore),
                  ),
                  isEmpty: widget.request.rayon == null,
                  child: new DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: widget.request.rayon.toString(),
                    isDense: true,
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        widget.request.rayon = int.parse(newValue);
                      });
                    },
                    items: _rayons.keys.map((int key) {
                      return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: key.toString(),
                        child: new Text(_rayons[key]),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),

                new GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    print("Container clicked");

                    Prediction p = await showGooglePlacesAutocomplete(
                        context: context,
                        apiKey: Consts.googlePlacesApiKey,
                        mode: Mode.fullscreen,
                        language: "fr",
                        components: [new Component(Component.country, "fr")]);

                    if (p != null) {
                      (_scaffoldKey.currentState).showSnackBar(
                          new SnackBar(content: new Text(p.description)));
                    }
                  },
                  child: new TextFormField(
                    // controller: controller,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.room),
                      hintText: 'Où êtes vous ?',
                      labelText: 'Localisation',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                new Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: new Align(
                      alignment: const Alignment(0.0, -0.2),
                      child: new ButtonBar(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new RaisedButton(
                            child: const Text('ANNULER'),
                            onPressed: _fermerCritereRecherche,
                          ),
                          new RaisedButton(
                            child: const Text('VALIDER'),
                            onPressed: _valider,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

If i replace :

```
      new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            print("Container clicked");

            Prediction p = await showGooglePlacesAutocomplete(
                context: context,
                apiKey: Consts.googlePlacesApiKey,
                mode: Mode.fullscreen,
                language: "fr",
                components: [new Component(Component.country, "fr")]);

            if (p != null) {
              (_scaffoldKey.currentState).showSnackBar(
                  new SnackBar(content: new Text(p.description)));
            }
          },
          child: new TextFormField(
            // controller: controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.room),
              hintText: 'Où êtes vous ?',
              labelText: 'Localisation',
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

By a simple Container it is working :

```
   new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            print("Container clicked");

            Prediction p = await showGooglePlacesAutocomplete(
                context: context,
                apiKey: Consts.googlePlacesApiKey,
                mode: Mode.fullscreen,
                language: "fr",
                components: [new Component(Component.country, "fr")]);

            if (p != null) {
              (_scaffoldKey.currentState).showSnackBar(
                  new SnackBar(content: new Text(p.description)));
            }
          },
          child: new Container(
             width: 80.0,
             height: 80.0,
             margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
             color: Colors.black),
        ),
```

Do you have any ideas how to make GestureDetector work with TextFormField ? Maybe with a controller but i have tried without any success
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Simply use `onTap` Method of `TextFormField`:

```
TextFormField(
  onTap: () {
    print("I'm here!!!");
  }
)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It worked for me like as expected.

Comment: This form of OnTap doesnt seem to have TapDownDetails which are useful for getting position information, GestureDetector does

Answer (score 21):

Wrap TextFormField widget With AbsorbPointer widget , then OnTap()  works definitely

here is an example:-

```
  GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => dialog(),
        child: AbsorbPointer(
          child: TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.grey,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius:
                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]),
                    gapPadding: 4),
                labelText: "Enter your mood",
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    letterSpacing: 1,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 13),
                hintMaxLines: 1),
            validator: (val) {
              if (val == "") return "Field can't be empty";
            },
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            enabled: true,
            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            minLines: 3,
            autofocus: false,
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            maxLines: 10,

          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Wrap AbsorbPointer Widget with Gesture Detector, and then work in onTap(). it will work fine.

Comment: Why? @relascope .. how can you say this

Comment: @relascope , The question is Tap event on TextFormField   and this the answer which is working fine. if you have better option please post your answer here... So i can see also

Comment: @SumitSingh Thanks. Solved my problem.

Comment: That could have been a valid option, but if your tetxFormField has a suffix or prefix icon widget which is tappable, then it doesn't work as expected.  Better use ontap of TextFormField

Answer (score 8):

I have found a solution by using the InputDecorator (from the flutter gallery) :

```
          child: new InputDecorator(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Localisation',
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.room),
                ),
                child: widget.request.localisationLibelle != null
                    ? new Text(widget.request.localisationLibelle)
                    : new Text("-- Choisissez un lieu --"),
              ),
```

Instead of using a TextFormField that catch the tap at the place of the GestureDetector I use a simple child Text of the InputDecorator widget.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this myself using Flutter 0.6.0.

The GestureDetector object takes in a behavior property [from this enum](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/HitTestBehavior-class.html) to determine how to defer actions.

Small snippet of the GestureDetector taking priority over a TextFormField:

```
new GestureDetector(
   onTap: onTap,
   behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
   child: new TextFormField(
     enabled: onTap == null,
     *other stuff here*
   ),
)
```

The onTap object is a Function object I declare outside of this. I also set the enabled property based on my onTap object, so I can ensure that if I want to capture a tap, the text form field is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

`onTap` function is working but if you use it with `InputDecoration { enabled: false }`, it will not working.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    enabled: false, // not working when on tap
    isDense: true,
    filled: true,
    fillColor: _listRadioItemPosition.isEmpty ? Colors.grey[100] : Colors.white,
    border: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFC4C4C4), width: 1)),
  ),
   onTap: (){
    displayBottomSheetPosition(context);
  },
```